# Treating files by using Julia language

Tags: file, julia

I'm a Julia beginner (scripting beginner too).

I have a text file which consists in 4 columns:

```
1 5.4 9.5 19.5

2 5.4 9.4 20.6

2 6.2 9.6 18.3

1 9.1 0.5 17.2

2 8.5 1.4 19.6

2 8.4 0.6 24.1

etc.
```

I have no idea how in Julia I can replace certain values in the rows or add a new one according to a existing column pattern 122 122. For example I would like to add the column with letter C and O (C when is 1 in the first column and O when is 2). I would like to add new column after the one with C and O where the pattern 1 2 2 is designated by number 4 and next by number 5. This is how I imagine the result:

```
C 4 1 5.4 9.5 19.5 

O 4 2 5.4 9.4 20.6

O 4 2 6.2 9.6 18.3

C 5 1 9.1 0.5 17.2

O 5 2 8.5 1.4 19.6

O 5 2 8.4 0.6 24.1
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Kasia.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what you want to see in the second column. I.e. after three 4 and then three 5, should three 6 etc. follow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String processing is fairly straightforward in Julia. You might write a function that takes an input and output filename as follows:

```
function munge_file(in::AbstractString, out::AbstractString)
    # open the output file for writing
    open(out, "w") do out_io
        # open the input file for reading
        open(in, "r") do in_io
            # and process the contents
            munge_file(in_io, out_io)
        end
    end
end
```

Now, the inner call to `munge_file` will have to do the actual work (this isn't particularly optimized, but should very straightforward):

```
function munge_file(input::IO, io::IO = IOBuffer())
    # initialize the pattern index
    pattern_index = 3
    # iterate over each line of the input
    for line in eachline(input)
        # skip empty lines
        isempty(line) && continue
        # split the current line into parts 
        parts = split(line, ' ')
        # this line doesn't conform to the specified input pattern
        # might be better to throw an error here
        length(parts) == 4 || continue
        # this line starts a new pattern if the first character is a 1
        is_start = parse(Int, parts[1]) == 1
        # increment the counter (for the second output column)
        pattern_index += is_start
        # first column depends on whether a 1 2 2 pattern starts here or not
        print(io, is_start ? 'C' : 'O')
        print(io, ' ')
        # print the pattern counter
        print(io, pattern_index)
        print(io, ' ')
        # print the original line
        println(io, line)
    end
    return io
end
```

Using the code in the REPL produces the expected output:

```
shell> cat input.txt
1 5.4 9.5 19.5
2 5.4 9.4 20.6
2 6.2 9.6 18.3
1 9.1 0.5 17.2
2 8.5 1.4 19.6
2 8.4 0.6 24.1 

julia> munge_file("input.txt", "output.txt")
IOStream(<file output.txt>)

shell> cat output.txt
C 4 1 5.4 9.5 19.5
O 4 2 5.4 9.4 20.6
O 4 2 6.2 9.6 18.3
C 5 1 9.1 0.5 17.2
O 5 2 8.5 1.4 19.6
O 5 2 8.4 0.6 24.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your file is `input.txt` you could do:

```
open("output.txt","w") do f
    println.(Ref(f),replace.(replace.(readlines("input.txt"),r"^1 "=>"C "), r"^2 "=>"O "))
end;
```

Dots (`.`) in the above code vectorize it so functions work on vectors rather than scalars. The `replace` function takes a `String`, regular expression and new value. `^` in regular expression means "line starts with".